# Syncing SQLite DB from MySQL after logging in

Tags: android-sqlite

I've been currently researching about the SQLite especially when it's involving logging in and registering. Here I managed to figured out that upon registering, the data would appear on appear in the table. But if I were to login without registering first, validating using data from MySQL, the data would not be passed on and inserted into the table.

This is a very weird occurrence as I thought codes from where I did my researched from, learn2crack's and AndroidHive's, would already solve this problem. Or I might have missed something here.

So I thought if I were to insert data of the user into the SQLite on the LoginActivity, maybe I need to pass the data from MySQL to SQLite. If the user is already existed on the SQLite, then it will not insert a new row but updates it? I'm not sure if this is the best way to overcome this but I would really appreciate any advise for this.

Otherwise, right now I'm just having trouble checking for existing user on SQLite. Because if I did this:

```
public void syncUser(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
    String selectUsernameQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN + " WHERE " + KEY_USERNAME + " = ?";
```

I can't figured out how to pass "USERNAME" (from EditText) from LoginActivity to my SQLiteHelper, where I can check for existing username in SQLite. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the user is already existed on the SQLite, then it will not insert
>   a new row but updates it?

Oh I've finally figured this out. I was creating new multiple rows every time I logged into the app as I thought I was supposed to get ALL the users' data from MySQL in sync with SQLite DB. And I wasn't deleting the previous row(s) upon logging out.

> But if I were to login without registering first, validating using data from MySQL, the data would not be passed on and inserted into the table.

I was definitely having difficulty trying to sync the data from MySQL with SQLite. But I managed to finally make it happen thanks to simple Volley POST method. Here is the updated working code that solved my problem:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // Clear all previous data in SQLite and fetches data from MySQL through JSON;
                        // Then, will pass the parameters obtain from MySQL to SQLite
                        JSONObject userObj = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        sqLiteHandler.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        sqLiteHandler.addUser(userObj.getString("uid"),
                                userObj.getString("username"),
                                userObj.getString("first_name"),
                                userObj.getString("last_name"),
                                userObj.getString("email"),
                                userObj.getString("type_of_tradesman"),
                                userObj.getString("picture"),
                                userObj.getString("user_description"),
                                userObj.getString("phone_number"),
                                userObj.getString("phone_service"),
                                userObj.getString("location"),
                                userObj.getString("lat"),
                                userObj.getString("lng"),
                                userObj.getString("created_at"));

                        // User successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        session.setLogin(true);

                        // Launch main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        String successMsg = "Welcome to XXX, " + username + "!";
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), successMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tag", "login");
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }
        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, tag_string_req);
```

addUser() method:

```
/**
 * Storing user details in database from the app's registration page
 */
public void addUser(String uid,
                    String username,
                    String first_name,
                    String last_name,
                    String email,
                    String type_of_tradesman,
                    String picture,
                    String user_description,
                    String phone_number,
                    String phone_service,
                    String location,
                    String lat,
                    String lng,
                    String created_at) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_UID, uid);
    values.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
    values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, first_name);
    values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, last_name);
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    values.put(KEY_TYPE_OF_TRADESMAN, type_of_tradesman);
    values.put(KEY_PICTURE, picture);
    values.put(KEY_USER_DESCRIPTION, user_description);
    values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER, phone_number);
    values.put(KEY_PHONE_SERVICE, phone_service);
    values.put(KEY_LOCATION, location);
    values.put(KEY_LAT, lat);
    values.put(KEY_LNG, lng);
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at);

    // Inserting Row
    long id = db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
    db.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into SQLite row number " + id);
}
```